# Git repository with only remote branches for production

Tags: git

On the remote production branch, I don't do any changes, so I don't need any branches.

I always want it mirrored to the origin production `git checkout origin production` works.

But, I can't seem to pull after that.

Is creating a local branch that tracks the origin production by

```
git checkout -b production --track origin production
```

the only option, or, I'm wondering, if there is any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the only option of you want to make some commits on a local branch named after a remote-tracking one

You can use the shortcut

```
git checkout -b --track origin/production
```

That way, you will be able to pull, since a pull is:

- a fetch (into `FETCH_HEAD`, not into `remote/origin/production`, that is unless `remote.origin.fetch` is set to a gobbling refspec like `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`)
- *plus* a merge, and the merge needs potentially to make a commit (which is only possible in a local branch, or on a detach head -- not recommended.)

Comment: So then I guess, I can always remain in the origin/production and do a fetch?

Comment: Yes, if you `git fetch origin`, because if you do git fetch origin production, then only FETCH_HEAD would be updated, and not your remote tracking branch)